# Communication between reliable services

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, rpc, azure-service-fabric

Microsoft offers a couple of different options of communication protocols to communicate between reliable services.

There are the default stack (strongly typed RPC), HTTP, WCF or custom protocols. I think the easiest way is to use the default communication stack. But what is the communication stack with the best performance?

Answer (score 1):

How are you defining performance? Highest number of request-responses in a given amount of time? Shortest amount of time for a single request-response? Memory or CPU overhead on the sender and receiver?

The stack with the best performance will usually be the custom one you write 
yourself specifically for your service communication characteristics. Every other stack is going behave differently depending on the situation.

Here's an example. Say you're streaming large amounts of data between services. HTTP might be a better choice than RPC here because you can open a connection and stream data as it arrives, whereas RPC will send it all in one big payload which leaves a big memory footprint. An even better option might be to open a WebSocket. An even *better* option than that would be to just use a regular socket.

Btw, We're no longer calling it the "default" stack because there isn't really a default - you have to choose one. The strongly typed RPC stack is now simply referred to as "Remoting."